# android computer app calculator design

Tags: android, android-layout

Ok so the problem basicly is I want to make my android calculator UI look like this can anybody give any suggestions or help? Much appreciated!

[Desktop Calculator App](http://file:///C:/Users/doronimo713/Desktop/CalculatorPic.png)

> and the code:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:weightSum="10"
   >


    <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/tv"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/zero"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_weight="2.5"



            />



    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="2.5"     
    >


    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/number7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/seven"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="findWhichButtonClickedOn"
    />

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/number8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/eight"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="findWhichButtonClickedOn"

    />

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/number9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/nine"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="findWhichButtonClickedOn"
    />

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/dividesign"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/divide"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="findWhichButtonClickedOn"
    />

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/signpercent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/percent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="findWhichButtonClickedOn"

    />










     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="2.5"
     >

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/number4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/four"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="findWhichButtonClickedOn"

    />

     <Button 
    android:id="@+id/number5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/five"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="findWhichButtonClickedOn"

    />

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/number6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/six"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="findWhichButtonClickedOn"

    />

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/multiplysign"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/multiply"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="findWhichButtonClickedOn"

    />

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/onedividexsign"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/onedividex"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="findWhichButtonClickedOn"

    /> 
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layoutrest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="2.5">

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    >

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/number1"
    android:layout_width="71dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/one"
    android:onClick="findWhichButtonClickedOn"
    />
    <!--  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    />-->

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/number2"
    android:layout_width="71dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/two"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/number1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/number1"
    android:onClick="findWhichButtonClickedOn"

    />

     <Button 
    android:id="@+id/zero"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/zero"
    android:layout_below="@+id/number1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/number1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/number1"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/number2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/number2"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="findWhichButtonClickedOn"

    />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:weightSum="2">


    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/number3"
    android:layout_width="71dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/three"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="findWhichButtonClickedOn"

    />

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/dot"
    android:layout_width="71dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/dot"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="findWhichButtonClickedOn"

    />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layout4"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/layout4"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/minus"
    android:layout_width="71dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/minus"
    android:onClick="findWhichButtonClickedOn"

    />

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/plussign"
    android:layout_width="71dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add"
    android:onClick="findWhichButtonClickedOn"


    />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layout5"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/layout5"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/equalsign"
    android:layout_width="71dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/equals"
    android:onClick="findWhichButtonClickedOn"
     />
            </LinearLayout>

      </LinearLayout> 
      </LinearLayout>
```

but I can't seem to do it. This is my code and what mine looks like so far:

[MyCalcAppSoFar](http://file:///C:/Users/doronimo713/Downloads/MyCalcAppSoFar.jpg)``

Comment: A link to your C drive isn't very helpful.

Comment: I'm new here and it didn't let me upload a picture is there a way to upload pictures?

Comment: Yes, there is an image icon right next to code formatting icon. Edit this question and use that to upload an image

Comment: You are better off using a Grid View in your layout. Also please upload the end result Picture on SO as there is an inbuilt option.

Comment: Thanks guys but its not letting me upload images because I need to have 10 reputation points. Can you guys upvote my question or answer so I can do this please?

Answer (score 0):

the previous code looks good. I also have one solution that might helpful to you. There is an xml file which completely describes design for a calculator in android studio, you an use either java or kotlin as backend and add functionalities according to your requirements. Always free feel to add suggestion to my code. Thank you.
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:hint="Details"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/v_10pc_vertical"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/v_10pc_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="48dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/v_10pc_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/v_quarter_vertical"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/v_quarter_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25"
        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_memory_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cl_operations_buttons"
        android:background="#888"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/v_quarter_vertical"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_m_plus"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b_m_minus"
            android:text="M+"
            android:onClick="memPlusClicked"
            style="@style/style_calc_button.darker_bg" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_m_minus"
            style="@style/style_calc_button.darker_bg"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/b_m_plus"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b_m_r"
            android:text="M-"
            android:onClick="memMinusClicked"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_m_r"
            style="@style/style_calc_button.darker_bg"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/b_m_minus"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b_m_c"
            android:text="MR"
            android:onClick="memRecordClicked"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_m_c"
            style="@style/style_calc_button.darker_bg"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/b_m_r"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:text="MC"
            android:onClick="memClearClicked"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_operations_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cl_789"
        android:background="#888"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cl_memory_buttons"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_clear"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b_e_to_x"
            android:text="C"
            android:onClick="clearClicked"
            style="@style/style_calc_button.darker_bg"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_e_to_x"
            style="@style/style_calc_button.darker_bg"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/b_clear"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b_pi"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="eˣ"
            android:onClick="expo_clicked"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_pi"
            style="@style/style_calc_button.darker_bg"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/b_e_to_x"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b_div"
            android:text=""
            android:onClick="pi_clicked"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_div"
            style="@style/style_calc_button.orangebg"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/b_pi"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:text="  ÷   "
            android:onClick="op_clicked"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_789"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cl_456"
        android:background="#888"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cl_operations_buttons"
            >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b_7"
                android:onClick="numberClicked"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b_8"
                android:text="7"
                style="@style/style_calc_button"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b_8"
                android:onClick="numberClicked"
                style="@style/style_calc_button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/b_7"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b_9"
                android:text="8"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b_9"
                android:onClick="numberClicked"
                style="@style/style_calc_button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/b_8"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b_multiply"
                android:text="9"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b_multiply"
                style="@style/style_calc_button.orangebg"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/b_9"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:text="×"
                    android:onClick="op_clicked"
                />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_456"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cl_123"
        android:background="#888"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cl_789"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_4"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b_5"
            android:text="4"
            style="@style/style_calc_button"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_5"
            style="@style/style_calc_button"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/b_4"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b_6"
            android:text="5"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_6"
            style="@style/style_calc_button"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/b_5"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b_subtract"
            android:text="6"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_subtract"
            style="@style/style_calc_button.orangebg"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/b_6"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:text="-"
            android:onClick="op_clicked"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_123"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cl_0_equal"
        android:background="#888"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cl_456"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b_2"
            android:text="1"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            style="@style/style_calc_button"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_2"
            style="@style/style_calc_button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/b_1"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b_3"
            android:text="2"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_3"
            style="@style/style_calc_button"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/b_2"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b_addition"
            android:text="3"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_addition"
            style="@style/style_calc_button.orangebg"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/b_3"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:text="\u002b"
            android:onClick="op_clicked"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_0_equal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="#888"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cl_123"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_0"
            android:onClick="numberClicked"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b_per"
            android:text="0"
            style="@style/style_calc_button"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_per"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            style="@style/style_calc_button"
            android:text="%"
            android:onClick="perClicked"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/b_0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/v_center_horizontal"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_radix_point"
            style="@style/style_calc_button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:onClick="dotClicked"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/v_center_horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/b_equal"
            android:text="."
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_equal"
            style="@style/style_calc_button.orangebg"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/b_radix_point"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:text="="
            android:onClick="equal_clicked"

            />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/v_center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`